# python: urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename) How to change download path?

Tags: python, selenium

I have an Instagram Bot that downloads all posts of a user to D:\PythonProjects because the directory of my Project Folder is D:\PythonProjects\InstagramBot.  How can i change it to download to D:\PythonProjects\InstagramBot\downloads\user ?

For downloading I used the following code:

```
print("DOWNLOADING " + str(len(saved_video_links)) + " VIDEOS")
    time.sleep(1)
    for x in range (len(saved_video_links)):
        print("[" + str(len(saved_pic_links)+x+1) +"/" + str(amount_of_posts) + "]")
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(saved_video_links[x], username + "_vid_" + str(x) + ".mp4", MyProgressBar())
```

I appreciate you help very much :)

Comment: `username + "_vid_" + str(x) + ".mp4"` defines the path of where the file should be saved. Thus, you can change it to: `os.path.join(USER_FOLDER_PATH), "{0}_vid_{1}.mp4".format(username, x)`. USER_FOLDER_PATH can either be an absolute or relative path

Comment: I read that too and I could do absolute path, but I want it to be a relative path because I want to be able to move the InstagramBot folder around. Problem is I didn't quite get how to do a relative path...

Comment: You can get the path of the folder of your script file by using `THIS_FOLDER = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` then you can add the path to the user directory by using `download_folder = os.path.join(THIS_FOLDER, RELATIVE_PATH)`